# column "pg_search_***" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, pg, pg-search

```
Tool.select('tools.id, tools.name').search('f')
```

the above query works fine but

```
Tool.select('tools.id, tools.name').group('tools.id').search('f')
```

produces the error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column
"pg_search_3aaef8932e30f4464f664f.pg_search_469c73b9b63bebacc2607f"
must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...xt, '')), 'D') || to_tsvector('english',
coalesce(pg_search_...
```

I am using pg_search(https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) gem for full text search..
I am not able to figure out the reason even tried adding

```
group("tools.id, tools.*, #{PgSearch::Configuration.alias('tools')}.rank")
```

As mentioned in the read me but still same error.
What is the proper way to frame the query?

Answer (score 0):

PG requires all selected fields to be either present in the GROUP BY clause or in an aggregate function(eg: max, min) - if you're grouping by anything, of course.

I'm guessing a `pg_search` gem migration created a field named `pg_search_469c73b9b63bebacc2607f` on a table named `pg_search_3aaef8932e30f4464f664f` and that is part of your query, but isn't part of the GROUP BY clause.

I can't see how `#{PgSearch::Configuration.alias('tools')}.rank` would translate to `pg_search_3aaef8932e30f4464f664f.pg_search_469c73b9b63bebacc2607f`

Try using `group("tools.id, tools.name, pg_search_3aaef8932e30f4464f664f.pg_search_469c73b9b63bebacc2607f")` and see if you get rid of that error. If it works, try to find a programatic way of retrieving that `pg_search_469c73b9b63bebacc2607f` field name.

Given your example, I don't think grouping by `tools.id` is doing you any good, assuming `id` is unique. If you were joining with something else it could make sense, though.